# Get tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to happen after tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got some UITableViewCells that need to change their height depending on the length of the strings inside. I'm calculating the necessary height inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and then storing it in a variable (`self.specialRowHeight`). Then I've got:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == SPECIAL_SECTION) {
        return self.specialRowHeight;
    }
    else {
        return 44;
    }
}
```

Except that seems to be getting called before the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` bit, so it's always zero.

Is there a way around this, or perhaps a different way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gonna answer my own question here:

Originally I was pretty sure that the height calculations were tied to the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, and couldn't be moved elsewhere. With a bunch of restructuring, though, I was able to get that stuff out of there and into `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, which solves everything.

For anyone else who's trying to get auto-height-adjusted cells to work, here's some code that might help:

```
// Inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = self.numberOfTextRows;
// numberOfTextRows is an integer, declared in the class

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize theSize = [theObject.theStringToDisplay sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, 9999.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    // This gets the size of the rectangle needed to draw a multi-line string
    self.numberOfTextRows = round(theSize.height / 18);
    // 18 is the size of the font used in the text label
    // This will give us the number of lines in the multi-line string

    if ((indexPath.section == FIXED_HEIGHT_SECTION) || (self.numberOfTextRows < 2)) {
        return 44;
        // 44 is the default row height; use it for empty or one-line cells (or in other table sections)
    } else {
        return theSize.height + 16;
        // 16 seems to provide a decent space above/below; tweak to taste
    }
}
```

If you can think of a more accurate way to calculate the proper cell height, I'm all ears. :)

Comment: I'm not really sure why you devide the rect height by 18 and then multiply it again, but other than that I do it pretty much the same way.

Comment: Well, the first division is to find out how many rows are needed, so I can set `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines` correctly; if I don't set that, it all gets printed on one line. But yeah, I guess I could just use `theSize.height` in the last bit there, instead of `self.numberOfTextRows`.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity and simplification. Works really well now.

Comment: This can only work correctly if the only content of the cell is a text label.

Comment: sizeWithFont is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just set self.numberOfLines to 0 once and it would work the same. (If numberOfLines is set to 0 then the label uses as many rows as are needed.)

Comment: Um... numberOfTextRows is a custom class property, so it won't do anything other than what I tell it to. Are you thinking of cell.textLabel.numberOfLines?

Comment: At any rate, yes, one can set `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines` to `0`, but it's still useful to find out the actual number that will be used (for calculating the appropriate row height, as here, for example). Also I find the resulting code to be much clearer, as "0" isn't at all semantically helpful at a glance.

Answer (score -7):

My solution was to call the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` inside the implementation of `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` as following

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   [self tableView:aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   return headerHeight;
}
```

Comment: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for every (!) single row in your tableView. Because of this, expensive calls like `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should not be used.

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted as this method lets you test against the actual height of the cell even if the label is not the only content. This is however, very expensive.