# How to define the uitableviewcell height dynamically according by the text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a grouped uitableview. I have a lot of sections.
In the first section there is just one UITableViewCell. In this cell, I will show a text.

The problem is that I don't know the number of characters of the text and I would like to change the height of cell to show entire text.

can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: You must know the amount of text or how do you show the text in the cell?

Comment: Also, look at all of the related links to your question. And this one from 20 mins ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905494/adding-text-to-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the UItableViewDelegate method - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath you can return height for specific row. For that you must know the length of the string you want to display in that row. 
see this link [Get tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: to happen after tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352801/get-tableviewheightforrowatindexpath-to-happen-after-tableviewcellforrowatind)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Within that you will have to do all the calculations that you do in the cell's `layoutsubviews` or in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` too. For doing so you will have to figure out how long the text is. You will have to access the text in `cellForRowAtIindexPath` anyway. So why don't you know how long the text will be?

To determine the size of the actual text you can use NSSTring's `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem applying the code below and creating a property *numberOfTextRows*.

**(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)t heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

```
float height = 45.0f;

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        CGSize theSize = [self.strResult sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, 9999.0f) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        self.numberOfTextRows = round(theSize.height / 12);
        if ((indexPath.section == height) || (self.numberOfTextRows < 2)) {
            height = 45;
        } else {
            height = theSize.height + 16;
        }
    }

return height;
```

**(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

> cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
>
> cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = self.numberOfTextRows;